# Which is the best way to create custom tabs in Android 2.2

Tags: android, tabs

I would like to know which will be the best method to create custom tabs in Android 2.2.  something like this.

[image]

[image]

I know about the TabHost but not satisfied with its UI. I would like to create my own tab UI  in 2.2 like shown in the above pic. Please suggest me the best and easy method to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Create a custom view for your tab complete with state lists drawables and more!

Best tutorial for you:

http://joshclemm.com/blog/?p=136

And this is a example code:

http://code.google.com/p/android-custom-tabs/

Comment: I dont want to create the tabs using TabHost because designing of the tabs using TabHost is limited only. I would like to have full flexibility in designing the tabs.

Answer (score 0):

[ActionBarSherlock](http://actionbarsherlock.com/) has tab feature. You can download Demos Sample from [here](http://actionbarsherlock.com/download.html) and look at Tab Navigation Sample. I think you can find it useful.

Comment: Is there any compatibility feature for android to make the action bar work for versions less than 3.0 ?

Comment: ActionBarSherlock uses [Support Package](http://developer.android.com/sdk/compatibility-library.html) and all features can be used on android 2.x and up.